# Weekly newsletter box is too small

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Because a screenshot says more than a thousand words:

[image]

Iceweasel (Firefox) 38.2.1, Debian GNU/Linux (wheezy)

(Wow, that looks like a pencil to the right in the screenshot...)

Comment: Hmm. This *might* correct itself. The ad stuff in the sidebar is cached for a while, might still be showing old stuff. I'm checking.

Comment: It looks [the same](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3553/design-bug-scrollbar-to-the-right) to me...

Comment: Nevermind. Found the problem, fixing. (Or, rather, Kurtis is. I'm just here to claim credit.)

Comment: @Adam That's what bug reports are for. Good work finding the problem so quickly. Please post a quick answer here when the update has been pushed so I have something that I can accept later.

Comment: I haven't been able to trip this yet to see for myself, but from your screen shot I find the black text on dark-green background really hard to read.  Is that coming from the ad or from something local to you?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Nothing local that I am aware of. You're right.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling thanks.  [Followup bug report](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3558/28).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Looks like that has been fixed too. The text is now white for me, on the same dark green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this is being pushed and should be live shortly. Thanks!