# Design bug: scrollbar to the right

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I have <del>[two](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/weekly-newsletter-box-is-too-small)</del> one issue<del>s</del> with the otherwise *awesome* new site design:

[image: visual bugs in wb.SX design]

> I get a horizontal scrollbar despite a large enough window size.
>
> The same scrollbar and background image artifact is also visible on Worldbuilding Meta, but in greyscale.

System (if relevant): Firefox 46.0.1 on a Win10 x64 machine.

*Edit*: removed second bug report, as simultaneously covered by another poster.

Comment: I can't speak for them, but I think the design team will appreciate one post per bug. (I know I do.) #2 is covered by [Weekly newsletter box is too small](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3552/29) so you could simply [edit] that out (perhaps chiming in to that post with your environment and a confirmation that you see the same behavior) and leave the other one.

Comment: Investigating the scrollbar issue. Thanks.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I have this exact same issue(s) on my Sony Tablet running Chrome 50.0.2661.89 (Android 6.0)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling done!

Comment: @ojdo I saw, very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just pushed a fix. This should be live in a moment. Thanks!

Comment: The bug still shows on my iPad...

Comment: It's alive for me.

Comment: Never mind, it's fixed ;)