# Text in newsletter ad is hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I'm borrowing this screen shot from [another post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3552/28):

[image: ad screenshot]

I'm finding the black text on the dark-green background to be really hard to read.  Can we improve the legibility?  If the text were the same color as the light green in the logo it looks like it'd be clear (judging from the logo) while still using a site color.  (That's not a specific request; if there's something that works better, by all means do it.  I'm just trying to be helpful by proposing something instead of just complaining.)

Comment: The text is now white for me, and the box has grown to its proper size.

Comment: Oh good!  Thanks for the update.  (I still haven't seen that ad myself in normal browsing.)

Comment: Here's a new screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7AGQ.png